# C# Arrays, Quick Sort of Char

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I badly need help for my Homework, I have this code that sorts an int but what I need to do is to sort a characters.

```
List<int> unsorted = new List<int> { 9, 8, 7, 6 };
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (int x in unsorted)
    {
        textBox2.text = textBox2.text + x.ToString() + "";
    }
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     List<int> result = new List<int>(quicksort(unsorted));
     showsort(result)
 }
```

This homework is going to be passed by midnight and I still cant figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what's the question? Have you implemented the quick sort algorithm and you noticed that it doesn't work as you expect to?

Comment: characters and ints are almost the same thing. should be exactly the same, but with char instead of int

Comment: What's the definition of `quicksort` and `showsort`?

Comment: Simplest way would be to change all the `int` types to `char` types. Can you show us the code for `quicksort` ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `char` and `int` are implements [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. So you may change a signature of your `quicksort` like this

```
public List<T> quicksort<T>(List<T> a) where T : IComparable<T>
{
}
```

Then somewhere in `quicksort` you need to replace `<` operator with call to `CompareTo` and analyze result